# Einstein Notation over a Single Tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, trace

If I have a tensor $X^{\mu}{}_{\nu} = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e& f\\
g&h&i\\
\end{bmatrix}$ then what is $X^{\mu}_{\;\;\mu}$?

From what I understand it would be $(a,b,c)\cdot(a,b,c) +(d,e,f)\cdot(d,e,f)+(g,h,i)\cdot(g,h,i).  $

Is this correct?

Comment: The left most index indicates the row number, the right most index indicates the column number. So would it be $(a,b,c)\cdot(a,d,g) +(d,e,f)\cdot(b,e,h)+(c,f,i)\cdot(g,h,i).  $

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1254041/72459

By the way, why do you think that you can count the indices up independently? When $\mu=1$, you have $X^1_1$, there's no way to get e.g. $X^1_2$ in $X^\mu_\mu$.

Comment: The above mentioned is **not** a tensor: it is the *components* of a tensor in some particular basis.

Comment: So then it would just be $a+e+i$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
{\mathrm tr}\left(X\right) = X^{\mu}{}_{\mu} = X^{0}{}_{0} + X^{1}{}_{1} + X^{2}{}_{2} = a + e + i 
$$